# What is the way to upate latest image in ACR

Tags: azure, kubernetes, acr

Several questions in this post.  I'm using Azure Kubernetes service, and I have images in ACR.

When I use `kubectl run my-pod  --image my-acr/my-image`, does it use the image with latest tag, eg, `my-acr/my-image:latest`.

When I push the image built locally, I do things like

1. Build `my-image:v1`
2. Tag `my-image:v1` with `my-acr/my-image:latest`
3. Now, should I delete `my-acr/my-image:latest` from ACR first, then push it.  Or I can directly do the push?

Comment: The standard approach to this is to _not_ use a `:latest` tag.  Use a unique tag per build, and change the `image:` in your Deployment spec to match.  You can attempt to force Kubernetes to re-pull the image, but you lose things like the ability to roll back.